# CSS - Firefox background position doesnt work for me

Tags: css

I am trying to make work background position in Firefox, but no success. In google chrome it works.
Here is my css that works in google, but Firefox doesnt accept background-position-y: 37px;

```
{
padding-top: 14px;
height: 50px;
background: url('image.png') repeat-x;
background-position-y: 37px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [backgroundPositionX not working on Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948617/backgroundpositionx-not-working-on-firefox)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing like cross-browser `background-position-y`. It simply doesn't work everywhere and therefore shouldn't be used. You have to set both parameters in `background-position`.

Please have a look at this thread: [background-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475055/css-background-position/14475199#14475199) and links I referred to in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not know a `background-position-y` property.

Try to use the regular [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position) with two arguments:

```
background-position: 0% 37px;
```